# can't run sh script on mac

Tags: macos, sh

I can't run the script, it says the file doesn't exist, but it exists

I have a start.sh script

I open a terminal and go to the script locations

```
cd desktop
cd script
```

And as instructed, I'm entering `sudo chmod +x start.sh` after this i entering my pass
And I'm trying to run the script with the command `sudo ./start.sh` and i have a problem "sudo: unable to execute ./start.sh: No such file or directory" but the problem is that this file exists. I have git installed, nodejs too, everything I need for that script is installed. I have the latest macOS

Answer (score 1):

Probably you do not [set execute mode](https://cets.seas.upenn.edu/answers/chmod.html) on the file.

#### Verify Modes On Script

```bash
ls -l
```

As you can see, `execute` (`x`) mode is not set on the script here:

```
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 tamas  staff  29 Feb  2 10:30 start.sh
```

Indeed, you cannot run the script:

```bash
sudo ./start.sh
sudo: ./start.sh: command not found
```

#### Set Execute Mode

```bash
sudo chmod +x start.sh
```

Verify:

```bash
ls -l
```

Note the `x` flags:

```
total 8
-rwxr-xr-x  1 tamas  staff  29 Feb  2 10:39 start.sh
```

Finally:

```bash
sudo ./start.sh
It works
```

Comment: but this command doesn't help me at all. It says "-rwxrwxr-x@ 1 olexiy  staff    1305  1 jan 17:42 start.sh" and I'm getting the error again "sudo: unable to execute ./start.sh: No such file or directory"

Comment: That makes sense! If you don't mind, I update your question with this information to help other folks on SO to find the solution for your problem.

Comment: @justnewbieorstmh please provide the start.sh's script first line. It should be a valid [shebang](https://linuxconfig.org/bash-script-shebang-usage-and-best-practices).

Comment: Yeah, sure, I'd appreciate it. I don't really know how to properly use everything here yet :)

Comment: 1st line #!/bin/bash

Comment: May I suggest to create a new script, like 'test.sh' with the following two lines: 1st: #!/bin/bash 2nd line: echo "it works!" -- save it and make it executable with chmod +x test.sh Now try to execute it via sudo ./test.sh
If it works, looks like your script isn't formatted well (CR / LF issues may arise, if it was originally authored on a Windows machine, for example).